# Prove that a certain sequence is increasing and find its limit: $a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n+1}=n(1+\ln a_n)$ (and $(a_n)^\frac{1}{n}$)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_1 = 1$ and $$a_{n+1}=n(1+\ln a_n).$$

I have to find its limit. I want to prove that it is increasing for starters, but I'm already stuck. What should I do?

I have also to find the limit of $(a_n)^\frac{1}{n}$. But this seems even more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $a_1 \geq 1$. We prove by induction that $a_n \geq 1$ for all $n$. Suppose that $a_k \geq 1$. Then $a_{k+1} = k(1+ \log(a_{k})) \geq k \geq 1$, so indeed $a_n \geq 1$ for all $n$. Now we have $a_{n+1} = n(1+\log(a_n)) \geq n$ for all $n$, which implies that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$.

Comment: You're right. I was overthinking it. Thank you. But what about the second one: $(a_n)^\frac{1}{n}$? It seems much more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

As for $\lim a_n^{1/n}$, prove by induction that $a_n\le n^2$. Then finish squeezing, using what user133281 already showed.

Comment: To be more accurate, $a_n\sim n\ln(n)$, and $\ln(a_n)=\ln(n)+\ln\ln(n)+\frac{\ln\ln(n)}{\ln(n)}+o(\frac{\ln\ln(n)}{\ln(n)})$

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Sure, correct remark. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To check whether it is increasing calculate the difference $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}$

It is equal to $(n^2-1)lna_n $ while $a_1$,the first term is equal to 1..